# Creating a new Windows partition

Tags: windows

I am trying to create new partition for an ubuntu installation, but while shrinking the volume (D:) to use the 21 gb free space available as seen in the snapshot, windows shows only 7GB is shrinkable. I tried defraging the logical volume but it yielded the same result.

I would like to know why this is as I am not able to use the complete 20 gb!

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 2):

This is because of immovable system files (like the pagefile for example). In order to get around this, try partitioning with a live CD of some sort (the [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) live CD has GParted which will do this easily).

Comment: Since you would be installing Ubuntu anyway, I'd suggest the Ubuntu LiveCD. Otherwise, I'd just go with the stand-alone [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). :)

Comment: @iglvzx, I didn't even realize that that was what his end goal was. To be honest, a ubuntu disk IS my Gparted live CD.